Custom IdP OIDC Connection failed to authenticate with unknown iss value (Next Auth)
I am connecting to a company OIDC compliant id provider. I'm getting errors that I cannot debug or get around.
Here is the configuration in auth.ts:
providers: [
    {
      id: "idam",
      name: "acmeIDAM",
      type: "oidc",
      wellKnown: "https://idam.acme.com/oauth2/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      authorization: "https://idam.acme.io/oauth2/authorize",
      token: "https://idam.acme.io/oauth2/token",
      userinfo: "https://idam.acme.io/oauth2/userinfo",
      clientId: process.env.OIDC_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET,
      profile(profile, tokens) {
        console.log("oauth profile ", profile, " tokens: ", tokens);
        return {
          id: profile.id,
          name: profile?.name,
        };
      },
    },
  ],
  basePath: "/auth",
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ request, auth }) {
      const { pathname } = request.nextUrl
      if (pathname === "/middleware-example") return !!auth
      return true
    },
    jwt({ token, trigger, session, account }) {
      console.log(`jwt callback: ${token} ${trigger} ${account}`)
      if (trigger === "update") token.name = session.user.name
      if (account?.provider === "keycloak") {
        return { ...token, accessToken: account.access_token }
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      console.log(`session callback: ${token} ${session}`)
      if (token?.accessToken) {
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken
      }
      return session
    },
  },
  experimental: {
    enableWebAuthn: true,
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? true : false,
} satisfies NextAuthConfig

This results in this error:

[auth][cause]: OperationProcessingError: unexpected JWT "iss" (issuer) claim value

But I cannot figure out what the value is. Adding into the configuration issuer: "localhost:3000" is not working either.
I don't have any help on how to get past this.

Error was that I was not matching the issuer value correctly. NextAuth package was blocking the incoming token that was returned because of that mismatch of value. Adding the right Issuer value solved it. this value is unique to the setup of each IdP you are working with, so I had to go check out my own auth app with my company system to figure this out. I thought at first is was localhost:3000 but that was not the case:
For example this was my solution.
 {
      id: "idam",
      name: "acmeIDAM",
      type: "oidc",
      wellKnown: "https://idam.acme.com/oauth2/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      authorization: "https://idam.acme.io/oauth2/authorize",
      token: "https://idam.acme.io/oauth2/token",
      userinfo: "https://idam.acme.io/oauth2/userinfo",
      issuer: "https://idam.acme.io/t/myappname/oauth2/token"
      clientId: process.env.OIDC_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET,
     
      },
    },
    ```


In my case, I added /.well-known/openid-configuration to my issuer URL, taking it out fixed it.

i have since learned that having the issuer and the token urls is often enough, since the wellKnown url, authorization url, and userinfo url are derivatives of those

Additionally, depending on your AUTH provider, you can "allow for login with out client secret", enforce mandatory PKCE, and then you dont have to use the client secret on the frontend service.
